# Product of a tempered distribution and bounded function is a tempered distribution?

Tags: functional-analysis

If $f$ is a tempered distribution and $g$ is bounded, then the product $fg$ is tempered distribution?
Thanks ins advance.

Comment: No. Or do you mean $g$ is smooth and Schwartz

Answer (score 1):

No. (Were you given more information about $g$ in the statement of the problem?) In fact the product $gu$ need not even *exist*:

Recall first that the definition of $gu$ is $$(gu)(\phi)=u(g\phi)\quad(\phi\in\mathcal S).$$

Define $u$ by $$u\phi=\phi'(0).$$. Let $$g(t)=\begin{cases}1,&(t\ge0),
\\-1,&(t<0).\end{cases}$$If there were  such a thing as $gu$ we would  have $$(gu)(\phi)=(g\phi)'(0).$$But  $(g\phi)'(0)$ need not exist for $\phi\in\mathcal S$.

Note assuming just that $g$ is infinitely differentiable is not enough; consider $u(\phi)=\int_0^\infty\phi$ and $g(t)=\sin\left(e^t\right)$. (Now $gu$ is a distribution, but not a tempered distribution.)

Comment: I have a doubt. 
$f$ is a tempered distribution then for any sequence $\varphi_j in S$ (schwartz space) with $\varphi_j\to 0$ then $f(\varphi_j)\to 0$

Now, $g$ is bounded then $|g(x)f(\varphi_j)|\leq M|f(\varphi_j)|\to 0$
Therefore $g(x)f(\cdot)$ is a tempered distribution.
Whats is wrong?

Comment: @eraldcoil Yes, for each fixed $x$, $g(x)f(\cdot)$ is a tempered distribution. So what? $g(x)f(\cdot)$ is not $gf$.